How to set up Webots development environment in VScode?（C++）
environment：

C++
Ubuntu20.04
vscode

Because my project is relatively large, it is difficult to use the built-in editor. Is there any process that can help me set up a development environment for Webots in Vscode, which can implement functions such as compiling and writing programs?

In fact, I have discovered a method myself in the past few weeks, see the link:https://blog.csdn.net/qq_42243147/article/details/142442860?spm=1001.2014.3001.5501

You can use the debug feature (attach using process id) if you are able to use python.


Start your Webots world.


Open the project on VS Code and open the python controller.
Click on the debug option "Debug using launch.json"

Select Python Debugger

Select "Attach using process id"

From the list of processes, select the one with the name of your controller.

After a while, the controls for debug will appear. You might need to click on pause and then step into.

You can now play around with the debugger for your robot.

